# LINQ expression doesn't work (Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a very simple `LINQ` expression here, but I don't see why it doesn't work.

I have a function like this:

```
public FileResult ImageForMovie(Int32? ID)
{
    String image = _entities.Movies
                            .Where(x => x.movie_ID == ID)
                            .Select(x => x.filename)
                            .First();

    return File("~/images/" + image, "image/jpg");
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the selection doesn't give any results. The view is okay, because if I write directly the image source, it gives the picture.

Comment: if it was giving you no results, `First()` would throw an exception. are you sure it's not returning `""` instead?

Comment: You should test if ID is null as it's "Int32?". Also use .SingleOrDefault() instead First and check if the image variable is not null before get the file.

Comment: Does the first record actually have a filename? This might be a data issue rather than a LINQ issue...

Comment: @MaxBündchen Schouldn't that be FIrstOrDefault() in this case?

Comment: @Thaoden Single throws an exception if there are multiple matches, First just returns the first in the series. So in this case, I think it's safe to assume that each Movie will have a different movie_ID. If that's not the case, we should have an exception thrown.

Comment: @Thaoden As it's searching by a unique ID, SingleOrDefault is the correct to me as there's just one or none return. The FirstOrDefault should be used if you get a list and want only the first one (or the default if the list is empty). Sure, in this case FirstOrDefault will work but just looks a misuse of the Linq.

Comment: We don't know if the ID is unique; the ID is nullable, so what would an item with a `null`-ID in a unique-ID-world be? What if there is more than one of them? If the OP is using `First()`, he'll have his reasons.

Comment: @grp-zeneszerzo You can also try to put the complete path in a variable before return the File(), so you can see the full url. In your sample the path looks like "~/images/FILENAMEimage/jpg". Is "FILENAMEimage" the correct path?

Comment: @Thaoden you are right, I just assume the ID is unique and propose the SingleOrDefault if it's the case. The problem is that the code don't test if the ID is null so it looks like a case where the ID is unique but the method lacks some checks (or a null ID is present in the database for a standard image).

Comment: @MaxBündchen yes, I tried. If I put directly the path, it works, so the image is okay. The database should be okay too, it has the good values in the table.

Comment: @DLeh you are right, it returns " ". Damn...